# Previously installed packages go missing in melda.io

Tags: r

In melda.io, I created a new data science project and installed R packages for it. When I come back to that project later, I see that the checkbox for that package is still selected but R complains that package cannot be loaded. I have to reinstall the package everytime. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal as the persistent storage feature has been added as of v0.8.0 which was released on Dec 31 2018. R packages previously installed are now persistently stored and available for subsequent sessions.